# How to select a random variable from a list for each iteration of a PHP generated for-each loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For each time my php code loops, it creates a new card for a cart item. I would like to have the background color of the card to be selected randomly from a list for each different card.

I added script to pick a random color and jquery selected the card, but it only changed the first item of the loop, and the rest are unaffected by the the jquery.

HTML + PHP:

```
<?php foreach($sArray as $sizeString){ ?>
div id="item_card" class = "cart_item_wrapper" >
<?php } ?>
```

script:

```
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
$('#item_card').css('background-color', random_color);
```

So, this only affects the first item card, I would like for every card's color to be randomly selected from the "colors" variable. 
Thank you.

Comment: `id="item_card"` `id`s should be unique in your HTML. Maybe use a class instead?

Comment: also, `div` is not the way to start a HTML tag. Also DIV is not a void type tag. It needs it's closing `</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make item_card id unique by concatenating a random number or an index of the looping array. Then, pass that to the script function as a parameter and use to apply the color.

For example:

```
<?php foreach($sArray as $index=> $sizeString){?>
    <div id="item_card<?php echo $index?>" class = "cart_item_wrapper"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Then,

```
function pickColor(index) {
    var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $('#item_card' + index).css('background-color', random_color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
div class="cart_item_wrapper item_card"
```

JS:

```
$('.item_card').css('background-color', random_color);
```

I know, right?

Comment: Close, but now all of the cards have the same random color, when I was looking for each card to have a different random color. But thank you